# How to push image value to a database using puppeteer?

Tags: sql, node.js, puppeteer

Puppeteer opens up a web page and takes a screenshot, how do I push this image value to an SQL database?

How do I convert the image value to a base64 form and then push that value into a database, all inside an async function?

```
const viewPort = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
const options = {
  path: 'new.png',
  fullPage: false,
  clip: {
    x: 771,
    y: 244,
    width: 168,
    height: 45
  }
};
const mysql = require("mysql");
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  database: "New",
  password : 'test'
});

(async function abc() {  
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport(viewPort)
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
  await page.screenshot(options); 

//I wish to enter this screenshot saved as new.png into the database

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`encoding: "base64"`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.18.1&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions) to your `options`
eg:

```
const options = {
  path: 'new.png',
  fullPage: false,
  clip: {
    x: 771,
    y: 244,
    width: 168,
    height: 45
  },
  encoding: "base64"
};
```

And then you create a variable to store your base64 String

`let imgBase64 = await page.screenshot(options);`

Now you can save the image in your database